# Multiple onchange and addition

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on creating a page in which someone could calculate their Net Worth by entering various values. The input text will show a .00 afterwards if no decimal point is added in. I'm having troubles in getting a sum of all of the values.

Java:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function updatesum() {
document.form.TotalAssets.value = (document.form.CashOnHand.value -0) + (document.form.CashInChecking.value -0);
}
//-->
</script>
```

HTML:

```
         <input type="text" onblur="if(this.value.indexOf('.')==-1)this.value=this.value+'.00'" onchange="format(this); updatesum()" onkeyup="format(this)" maxlength="11" value="0" name="CashOnHand" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Cash in Checking</strong></td>
        <td>$
          <input type="text"
onblur="if(this.value.indexOf('.')==-1)this.value=this.value+'.00'" onchange="format(this); updatesum()" onkeyup="format(this)" maxlength="11" value="0" name="CashInChecking" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right"><strong>Total Assets</strong></td>
        <td>$<input name="TotalAssets" readonly ></td>
      </tr>
```

It's not giving me a sum of the the values that I'm adding.

Comment: You haven't described what actual problem you are having, is a function not being called, are you getting the wrong sum, etc

Comment: How about if the user inputs some text like "aaa" ? suggest:input type can be "number" instead of "text". onblur/onkeyup/onchange can be replaced with oninput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because `document.form` is undefined, but this one works:

```
function updatesum() {
  var hand = parseFloat(document.forms[0].CashOnHand.value);
  var checking = parseFloat(document.forms[0].CashInChecking.value);
  document.forms[0].TotalAssets.value = hand - checking;
}
```

Comment: Every time I have removed the if to get rid of the .00 and removed the value="0" it stops adding them up and also shows NaN until I entered the 2nd value. Why is this?

Comment: You can use event listeners in your javascript files and listen for `blur`, `change`, and `keyup` events and just place your event handler in there. You can use `addEventListener` for this.